Azure Resource Graph - Database sizes
I have recently begun using Azure Resource Graph to query and pull reports across our entire estate regarding our azure databases. I've managed to pull a lot of useful data out from the resources table but I'm brand new to KQL and graph in general and am unsure of where else to look for the monitoring data such as used space, remaining space etc.
The query I'm running currently is:
resources
| where type =~ 'microsoft.sql/servers'
| project serverName = name, serverLocation = location, serverResourceGroup = resourceGroup, serverFQDN = properties.fullyQualifiedDomainName, serverLocalAdminAccount = properties.administratorLogin, serverAdminGroup = properties.administrators.login, serverTags = tags
| join (resources
| where type =~ 'microsoft.sql/servers/databases' and name != 'master'
| extend serverName = extract("servers/(.*)/databases", 1, id)
| project serverName, databaseName = name, databaseCreationDate = format_datetime(todatetime(properties.creationDate), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'), databaseStatus = properties.status, databaseBackupStorageRedundancy = properties.requestedBackupStorageRedundancy, databaseZoneRedundant = properties.zoneRedundant, databaseCollation = properties.collation, databaseEarliestRestoreDate = format_datetime(todatetime(properties.earliestRestoreDate), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'), elasticPoolId = tolower(properties.elasticPoolId)) on serverName
| project-away serverName1
| join kind=leftouter (resources
  | where type =~ 'microsoft.sql/servers/elasticpools'
  | project elasticPoolId = tolower(id), elasticPoolName = name, elasticPoolState = properties.state) on elasticPoolId
| project-away elasticPoolId, elasticPoolId1

I'll admit that at first glance, I thought I'd find everything I needed within those 3 types but evidently there must be something else I'm missing?

What is your actual question? You can just query for resources| where type =~ 'microsoft.sql/servers' to see every field which is available.

Heya, in short, the question is: Where are the data sizes for azure databases stored? I've not managed to find it within the areas in my existing query so I'm assuming it exists elsewhere

I have posted an answer. Please check it out.

Maybe this query could help you:
resources 
| where type == "microsoft.sql/servers/databases" 
| project
    resourceGroup,
    serverName = split(id, "/")[8],
    databaseName = name,
    sku = properties.sku.name,
    status = properties.status,
    maxSizeBytes = toint(properties.maxSizeBytes),
    maxSizeGB = maxSizeBytes / (1024 * 1024 * 1024),
    usedSpaceMB = properties.currentUsedStorageBytes / (1024 * 1024) 
| order by databaseName asc


Thank you! Sadly the currentUsedStorageBytes column appears to all just be null but that did answer my question :)

Great :) You could also project just properties maybe you find something useful.
